# Expected number of rolls to get streak of three increasing rolls

Tags: probability, expected-value, dice

You roll a fair, 6-sided die repeatedly until you get a streak of three increasing rolls (three consecutive rolls with numbers in strictly increasing order, but not necessarily consecutive numbers). What is the expected number of rolls?

If we let $X$ be the number of rolls until we satisfy our required condition, let $E=\mathbb{E}[X]$ and $E_i = \mathbb{E}[X\space|\space i], \space i\in\{1,\dots, 6\}$. So $E_1$ is the expected number of rolls until we satisfy our required given that we have currently rolled a 1, meaning that, for instance $E_{31} = E_1$ where we define $E_{ij}$ similarly (rolled an $i$ and then a $j$).

Using this notation and considering the first roll, I found, $E = \frac{1}{6}(1 + E_1) + \frac{1}{6}(1+E_2) + \frac{1}{6}(1+E_3) + \frac{1}{6}(1+E_4) + \frac{1}{6}(1+E)  + \frac{1}{6}(1+E)$

$\implies \frac{2}{3}E = 1 + \frac{1}{6}(E_1 + E_2 + E_3 + E_4)$

given that $E_5 = E_6 = E$.

Similarly, by considering the scenario where we have rolled a 4, I found $E_4 = \frac{1}{6}(1+E_1) + \frac{1}{6}(1+E_2) + \frac{1}{6}(1+E_3) + \frac{1}{6}(1+E_4) + \frac{1}{6}(1+E_{45}) + \frac{1}{6}(1+E)$

where $E_{45} = \frac{1}{6}(1+E_1)+\frac{1}{6}(1+E_2)+\frac{1}{6}(1+E_3)+\frac{1}{6}(1+E_4)+\frac{1}{6}(1+E)+\frac{1}{6}\cdot 1 $

$= 1 + \frac{1}{6}(E+E_1 + E_2 + E_3 + E_4)$

and so

$E_4 = \frac{7}{6} + \frac{7}{36}(E + E_1 + E_2 + E_3 + E_4)$

It seems that by continuing in this fashion I can find $E_1, E_2, E_3$ in terms of $E$ and the other $E_i$'s but will be become increasing tedious as we go from $E_3$ to $E_1$. However, after finding other linear equations involving $E$ and the $E_i$'s, we could find $E$ by inverting a matrix so the method seems to work, but is quite long and would not be very feasible to use when considering an $n$ sided dice.

I was wondering if there is a nicer approach to this problem which would also allow a generalisation to an $n$ sided dice?

Comment: Best I can think of at first is to introduce states corresponding to the last two throws (including states for the last throw if last two failed to increase).  Thus the state $(1,5)$ would mean that the last throw was a $5$ and the one before it was a $1$.  From that state we have a $\frac 16$ chance of finishing on the next turn, and then a $\frac 16$ chance of moving to one of states $(1), (2), \cdots, (5)$.  Not too painful, but you have a quadratic number of states as $n$ grows.  Even if many of the states, like $(x6)$ are easily handled, there are an awful lot of active states.

Comment: Oh, it's not so bad.  After all, you are either done in $3$ steps or you revert to one of the single roll states.  That is, the transitions are very simple.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate a bit more on what you mean in your second comment?

Comment: There are no transitions between the two roll states.  If you are in the two roll state $(i,j)$ with $i<j$ you either finish with probability $\frac {n-j}n$, assuming an $n-$sided die, or you revert to one of the single roll states $(1), (2), \cdots, (j)$ with probability $\frac 1n$ for each.  That makes it pretty easy to sort out.

Comment: @lulu I think you only need to consider at most $(k-1)n +2$ states where you want $k$ increasing values from $n$ sided dice: the $2$ are the start and finish while you also want the most recent roll to have been $m$ with $j$ increasing values in a row.

Comment: For a $6-$sided die, there are only $15$ two roll states so there is no difficulty enumerating all the cases.  Of course, for an $n-$sided die, there are $\frac {n(n-1)}2$ two roll states so it gets a little messier.

Comment: @Henry. Oh, good point.  So we only need to consider the last roll really, plus something telling us if it is part of a two roll state (or part of a $k$ roll state for higher $k$) or not.  Yes, you are right.  That makes it a lot easier.  Definitely linear in $n$.

Comment: @idk31909310  Did you get Henry's point?  My method keeps track of states like $(14)$ and $(24)$ separately which is not necessary.  All that matters is that the last roll was a $4$ and that $4$ was part of a two term increasing sequence.  That's much more efficient.  Linear in $n$ even if you ask about increasing sequences of length $k$.  For $n=6$ the difference hardly matters, but for higher $n$ this is an important observation.

Comment: It seems the solution may be $\frac{6^6}{3781}$ and simulation suggests that this is plausible.  A wrong argument might give the slightly higher $2+\frac{6^3}{6 \choose 3}$.